# How to take data in one r file and use it to replace part of the data in a different one

Tags: r, merge, duplicates, rbind

I have two datasets in r, one has a column with information I would like to add to the other one, which is currently filled with NA.

To give you an idea, this is what the two datasets look like:

DATASET 1:

```
id || location || city name
1 || 54.234 || name1
2 || NA || name2
3 || NA || name3
4 || 55.2345 || name4
```

DATASET 2:

```
id || location || city name
2 || 57.234 || name2
3 || 58.234 || name3
```

I want to end up with the following:

```
id || location || city name
1 || 54.234 || name1
2 || 57.234 || name2
3 || 58.234 || name3
4 || 55.2345 || name4
```

Right now, I am using this:

```
dataSetFinal <- rbind(dataSet1, dataSet2, by="id")
```

but this duplicates the lines with the ids they have in common and adds the respective locations in the duplicates. How can I get the desired result? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We can join the two dataset by `id` and `city.name` and then select non-NA columns from `location` using `coalesce`.

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(df1, df2, by = c('id', 'city.name')) %>%
  mutate(location = coalesce(location.x, location.y)) %>%
  select(names(df1))

#  id location city.name
#1  1  54.2340     name1
#2  2  57.2340     name2
#3  3  58.2340     name3
#4  4  55.2345     name4
```

Or in base R :

```
transform(merge(df1, df2, by = c('id', 'city.name'), all.x = TRUE), 
      location = ifelse(is.na(location.x), location.y, location.x))[names(df1)]
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:4, location = c(54.234, NA, NA, 55.2345
), city.name = structure(1:4, .Label = c("name1", "name2", "name3", 
"name4"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df2 <- structure(list(id = 2:3, location = c(57.234, 58.234), 
city.name = structure(1:2, .Label = c("name2", "name3"), class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: How do I then ensure that I get a dataset back that has the same initial column names and not duplicate them in a .y .x fashion?

Comment: @VictorDanielCardenas In both the approaches I have made sure that you get the dataset with initial columns by using `names(df1)` to subset the columns.